# Add Multiline Values to single HTML Cell

Tags: html, arrays, powershell

I'm working on a reporting script that should list the currently configured teammembers of a specific user. The endresult is a HTML page which lists all users with their properties incl. teammembers.

Basically I store all the user information in PSCustomObject:

```
$UserObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Team" -Value $Settings.Teammembers
...
$AllObject += $UserObject
...
$AllObject | ConvertTo-Html -Property * -Head "<H2>User</H2>" -CssUri $csspath |
    Out-File $outpath -Append
```

`$Settings.Teammembers` is an array of strings.

If I convert this as-Is to a HTML Page, all team members are listed on a single line:

```
user1@domain.com user2@domain.com
```

But at the end it should look like:

```
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
```

I tried following approaches:

- Added `` `n `` after every username. During debugging in ISE, the value looks fine, but in the HTML file it looks the same.
- Save all users in `$Settings.Teammembers` in a single variable `$UserTeam` followed by `-join`:

  ```
  $UserTeam = $UserTeam -join '<br/>'
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering HTML consecutive whitespaces is usually mangled into a single space. Because of that adding newlines won't give you wrapped text in the rendered HTML. You need to encode line breaks as `<br>` (or `<br/>`) to preserve them in the rendered HTML. However, you cannot join the list of team members with `<br/>` strings before the `ConvertTo-Html`, because then the angular brackets would be escaped to `&lt;br/&gt;` and you'd get literal `<br/>` in the rendered HTML output.

One way to retrofit line breaks into the prepared HTML is to replace spaces (or newlines) in a `<td>` using a regular expression replacement with a callback function:

```bsh
$html = $AllObject | ConvertTo-Html ...

$cb = {
    $args[0].Groups[1].Value +
    ($args[0].Groups[2].Value -replace '\n', '<br/>') +
    $args[0].Groups[3].Value
}
$re = [regex]'(<td>)(.*?)(</td>)'
$re.Replace($html, $cb) | Out-File ...
```

However, a more elegant approach would be a CSS format for `<td>` tags that defines [whitespace handling as pre-formatted](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) (similar to the `<pre>` tag). Adding something like this to your CSS file should suffice:

```css
td {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I tried the first approch and finally it works fine. I made slight adjustment to make it work, because I'm not sure if I handle '\n' correctly. Instead of '\n' I "terminate" the Username with "#" which will be replaced with the mentioned regex.

I'll have a look on the 2nd approch as well